# Can't remote desktop from OS X 10.6.8 to Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: macos, ubuntu, vnc

I'm trying to remote desktop from my OS X 10.6.8 Mac to an Ubuntu 11.04 box.

When I go to Finder > Go > Connect To Server, type in "VNC://devmta1.local" and hit return, the Mac displays "Contacting mtadev1.local..." with the non-progress progress bar (*what* is that called, anyway?).

On the Ubuntu side, I get a notice that "hanuman.local" is controlling my computer, then that goes and away, and then... nothing.  The "Contacting..." dialog box stays up on the Mac, but nothing else happens.

I've also tried with the IP address (but that doesn't make any difference).

Known issues?  Suggestions?

Comment: This isn't a direct solution to your specific problem, so forgive me if this is unhelpful, but: Even if you get OS X's VNC client to work, it's very poor. It doesn't support anything but the most basic protocol features and it doesn't have many UI options either. If it's possible to use an alternative client, i would recommend [JollysFastVNC](http://www.jinx.de/JollysFastVNC.html) (which i've personally used and enjoy) or maybe [Chicken](http://sourceforge.net/projects/chicken/) (which is open-source).